# 2D splitscreen views

Tags: c#, opengl, viewport, opentk

I'm using OpenTK to fiddle around with OpenGL a bit. Displaying an area on the entire window ain't no big deal anymore, but trying to get some sort of splitscreen mechanic in is. For one screen I'd do:

```
GL.Viewport(0, 0, window.Width / 2, window.Height);
GL.LoadIdentity();
GL.Ortho(0, 800, 600, 0, -1, 1);
```

In the GameWindow's resize event. How will I be able to display 2 of these next to eachother? And how can I make em both display a different area in my 'game'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way IMO, is to use two viewports.

Lets say you have 2 views, left and right, and that you will render the left view before the right one.

This way, you must setup your left viewport and projection, perform the left view rendering, setup the right viewport and projection, perform the right view rendering:

```
void draw() {
    // update your models or perform anything else here.
    (...)
    // setup your left view projection:
    GL.MatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    GL.LoadIdentity();
    GL.Viewport(0, 0, window.Width / 2, window.Height);
    GL.Ortho(0, 800, 600, 0, -1, 1);
    GL.MatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    // draw your left view.
    (...)
    // setup your right view projection:
    GL.MatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    GL.LoadIdentity();
    GL.Viewport(window.Width / 2, 0, window.Width, window.Height);
    GL.Ortho(0, 800, 600, 0, -1, 1);
    GL.MatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    // draw your left view.
    (...)
    // perform any cleanup you need.
    // swap buffers!
}
```

This is a very simplified code, but I hope it will give you a hint on how to do it.

Comment: Looks neat, but isn't drawing everything twice going to cause a lot of overhead or will OpenGL take care of that?

Comment: @Villermen If your views are simply different views of the same model (for example, your programing a CAD application with orthogonal and projection views) you can make this a lot better, but the solution is also a lot complex. Else, if you are implementing something like Mario Kart (love it!) split view, this is probably the best way to do it and also the simplest in all cases. What are you specifically trying to implement?

Comment: There is no specific use to this yet. I'm new to OpenGL and OpenTK so I'm trying to get the hang of it by setting some goals of things to get done and learn from. I'm going to create myself a simple 2D game engine that can utilize views, mainly for things like splitscreening.

Comment: @Villermen Than I would recommend to start with this simpler method. The other method I know involves multiple render passes with shaders and frame buffers and is a lot more complicated to explain. Would very easily make a whole book chapter or even more. Also, it is not supported on older hardware (maybe OpenGL 3.0 at last).

Comment: For now (and probably for a good long time) I think this is as complicated as I will go with views. Good thing your example turned out exactly as I envisioned the result I wanted to get. Thanks a lot for that btw!